# Google Maps API shows incorrect location for some locations but correct for other locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I am using Google Maps API, Google Places API and Autocomplete and have a map service where the customer can put in 2 locations and find out the distance between them and a fare charge with the map.

In general this has been working fine and calculating the correct locations but I've noticed for some locations Autocomplete brings up the address in the textbox but when it is geocoded and added to the map it brings up the incorrect location (of only what I can only assume is the cell tower location as it seems to go to this address for other addresses that don't work).

The location that doesn't work is in a more remote location with a far reaching postcode - could this be why google is unable to correctly pinpoint it on the map? Therefore do I need to just accept it won't work for every location input and add an error message. The problem is the location is available on google maps website but just doesn't play ball with the API.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show an example query that will demonstrate this?

Comment: Ok, for example Glasgow Airport to Cameron House Loch Lomond, Alexandria, West Dunbartonshire G83 8QZ

Find the website I'm working on [here](http://www.citycarsprivatehire.com/get-a-quote/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the following lines in your code:

`var start = document.getElementById("start").value + ', glasgow';`

`var end = document.getElementById("end").value + ', glasgow';`

You append ', glasgow' to the address displayed in autocomplete.

I suggest using placeId obtained directly from autocomplete boxes instead of address texts when you calculate a route. With place Ids you will calculate an exact route for places selected by the user: Currently, appending a text and passing this to directions service you can have really wrong results.

Please have a look at the example that shows how to implement autocomplete with place Ids:

http://jsbin.com/ponoyod/4/edit?html,output